# make: *** [Makefile:1686: modules] Error 2

Tags: networking, drivers, make, tp-link

I was trying to install a wifi driver in my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. 5.11.0-36-generic and hp laptop.

I ran these commands:

```
cd Downloads
cd TL-WN8200ND 2.0_LinuxDriverSetup
cd rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1.1_18873.20160805_BTCOEX20160412-0042-OK
make clean
make
```

After `make` I get this output in terminal:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.11.0-36-generic/build M=/home/adji/Downloads/TL-WN8200ND 2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1.1_18873.20160805_BTCOEX20160412-0042-OK  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-36-generic'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1.1_18873.20160805_BTCOEX20160412-0042-OK'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-36-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1686: modules] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

> cd TL-WN8200ND 2.0_LinuxDriverSetup

Bash doesn't like spaces in names. Please right-click the folder and rename it; something like *TL-WN8200ND_driver*. Then try again:

```
cd Downloads
cd TL-WN8200ND_driver
cd rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1.1_18873.20160805_BTCOEX20160412-0042-OK
make clean
make
```

Also, you can combine the commands:

```
cd Downloads/TL-WN8200ND_driver/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1.1_18873.20160805_BTCOEX20160412-0042-OK
make clean
make
```

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Is it actually the same? " *** No rule to make target '2.0_LinuxDriverSetup/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1.1_18873.20160805_BTCOEX20160412-0042-OK'.  Stop." Is the Makefile in that directory? `cd ~/Downloads/TL-WN8200ND_driver/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1.1_18873.20160805_BTCOEX20160412-0042-OK && ls`